# SwiftUI - How can I filter users of a list with a datepicker

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm creating an app with **SwiftUI**. I have an array of data and a list showing them. The array contains various elements which contain a username and a date for each element. Something like that:

```
struct History: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var userName: String
    var date:String
 }

var itemsHistory = [
    History(userName: "Liam", date: "2020-06-17" ),
    History(userName: "Noah", date: "2019-04-14" ),
    History(userName: "James", date: "2022-04-13" ),
]
```

---

```
List {
  ForEach(itemsHistory) { item in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text(item.userName)
        .font(.headline)
      Text(item.date)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
     }
   }
  }
}
```

*My question is:*
How can I use one or two `datapickers` to **only show users in a certain date range**? For example: from the `datepicker` I select the range between 2020-01-01 and 2020-02-12 and the list must show only the users who have the date that is in that range.

Thank you very much. It is the first time that I am writing here.

Answer (score 1):

First declare `date` as `Date`, it's easier to compare

```
struct History: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var userName: String
    var date: Date
 }
```

Get start and end date from the pickers

```
@State private var startDate = Date()
@State private var endDate = Date()

DatePicker(
    "Start Date",
    selection: $startDate,
    displayedComponents: [.date]
)
DatePicker(
    "End Date",
    selection: $endDate,
    displayedComponents: [.date]
)
```

Then filter the items

```
let filteredItems = endDate < startDate ? [] : itemsHistory.filter { item in
    (startDate...endDate).contains(item.date)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I assign a date to a date variabile? I tried like this but it doesn't seem to work and i can't find the way. `History(userName: "Liam", date: Date("2020-06-17") ),`

Comment: You need a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)